# Show custom Admin Messages In configuration section custom module Magento 1.x based on API response

Tags: magento-1.9, module, adminhtml, extensions, global-messages

I created a **`custom module`** which fetch data using third-party APIs.

In **`admin Dashboard`** after **`module installation`**.
I want to check few things form API( I am getting everything from API this is done , just need to show show message once admin activates the module ) If all is OK I want to show the message under the **Enable/Disable** button.

[image: errormesage section]

[image: inrsaurabh]

> If I try the below method ,  when I change the configuration values of my custom module. I hit API to validate few things

**This works**

> **Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('someotheremodule/debug/logenabled', '0', 'default', 0);
>       Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('smtpsomeotheremodulepro/debug/log_debug', '1', 'default', 0);**

**This is not working**

> **Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('reviewrating/section_one/active', '1', 'default', 0)**;

**How to change the config values by my custom module?**
Currently I  attached  **`<backend_model>reviewrating/Statuswidget</backend_model>`**  to one of the fields. Is it the only way to get values and in this way i have to use same process for each field?

> In 
>   `/var/www/html/magento16/app/code/local/Namespace/ReviewRating/etc/config.xml`

```
     <!-- ... -->
            <admin_system_config_changed_section_sectionone>
                <observers>
                    <mymodule>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_ReviewRating_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>changeSystemConfig</method>
                    </mymodule>
                </observers>
            </admin_system_config_changed_section_sectionone>
        </events>
  </global>
        <!-- ... -->
```

> In `/var/www/html/namespace/app/code/local/Namespace/ReviewRating/Model/Statuswidget.php`

```
<?php
/**
 *  
 * @author      inrsaurabh
 */

class Namespace_ReviewRating_Model_Statuswidget extends Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data
{

     protected function _beforeSave()
{
    $value = $this->getValue();
    Mage::log( $value );

    // if widget activated ( enable = 1 ) 


    $apidDataCheck = Mage::helper('reviewrating')->checkWidgetStatus( $value );
    $isError = $apidDataCheck['success'];
    Mage::log( $isError );

    if( $isError != 1 ){
        Mage::log('Disable module');

        Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('reviewrating/section_one/active', '0', 'default', 0);
// above line dont change config value 

        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addWarning( $isError ); 



    } else {
         Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess('Widget Enabled'); 
    }

}
```

> In `/var/www/html/magento16/app/code/local/Namespace/ReviewRating/etc/system.xml`

```
 <sections>
        <reviewrating translate="label" module="reviewrating">
            <!-- -->
              <groups>
                <section_one translate="label">
              <!-- -->
              <active translate="label comment">
                        <label>Widget Status </label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>54</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                        <backend_model>reviewrating/Statuswidget</backend_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
              </active>
              <!-- ... -->
              </section_one>
              <!--- -->
             </groups>
        <!-- -->
      </section>
```

Please suggest how to proceed. I didn't find any link related to this in which I can hit API on **`enable/disable`** button and then show messages.

Thank You.

Comment: Just create a front-end model class for this enable/disable field in which you can change element html before rendering. So just need to check for your condition before rendering this element in frontend modal class. So you can show message along with element.

Comment: @KumarM  i updated my question with my code can you guide.

Comment: Create an observer which will attach to system configuration save for that section. Inside observe call curl to hit API and get data once you got data set a variable into adminhtml session. And inside front end modal class just copy paste all methods from adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable and after it find code where this select option will be rendering inside that function get the value of session then print your message based on value set to the session.

Comment: @KumarM sir I didn't understood `methods from adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable` ? If possible can share any link on same topic.